# Boolean Method with a comparison nest loop for an array how to fix

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

So i have a assignment to create a boolean method that returns true or false if there is a duplicate integer within a given array of integers. the problem is the only way to check is to take each element and compare it with the others, kinda like  insertion sort almost.
the problem is that it cant read my result variable saying it isnt initiated 
Here is the code:

```
public static boolean hasDuplicate(int numOfElement, int[] numArr)
    {
    int numOfElements = numOfElement;
    int[] uncheckedArr = numArr;
    boolean result;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < numOfElement; i++) // takes an element in order from left to right
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < numOfElement; j++)
        {
            if (numArr[i] == numArr[j])
                result = true;
        }


    }
    return result;
}
```

My Question is how can i fix this? I want to have it stop as well once it detects a duplicate within the array. however i know break function only does the most inner loop. This is only a small layout as i kept changing the code a lot. I did try looking up this stuff online but cant seem to find the solution

Comment: `if (numArr[i] == numArr[j]) {return true;}` and get rid of `result` completely, and `return false;` at the end of the method.  Also, if there is enough memory, this can be done in a single loop by using a `Set` or Stream unique  and compare the size to the original array (that might be the next assignment).

Comment: Also you can remove: `int numOfElements = numOfElement;` and
    `int[] uncheckedArr = numArr;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like that:

```
public static boolean hasDuplicate(int numOfElement, int[] numArr) {
    boolean found = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (!found && i < numOfElement) {
        int j = i + 1;
        while (!found && j < numOfElement) {
            if (numArr[i] == numArr[j]) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Please check the code on your computer :) I cannot execute it from my phone :) What I'm trying to focus on is changing a bit your code, especially loop stop conditions.

Comment: Moreover, you can replace `found = true;` with `return true` and `return found` with `return false;`.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your boolean variable as false

```
boolean result = false;
```

Also, you can use the variables you received as a parameter, therefore these lines are useless

```
int numOfElements = numOfElement;
int[] uncheckedArr = numArr;
```

You can write your code like this:

```
public static boolean hasDuplicate(int[] numArr)
{  //Note that you dont need to pass numOfElements as a parameter!
   int numOfElements = numArr.length; 
   boolean result = false;

   for(int i=0;i<numOfElements;i++)
   {
       for(int j=i+1;j<numOfElements;j++)
       {
          if (numArr[i] == numArr[j])
          {
             result = true;
             return result; //You can just return true here, since you wanted to break the loops once you find duplicates
          }
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: @Gianlucca so the j++ is now a dead code and the problem now is if i dont use return there it wont break the nested loop but if i have it there the for loop wont run

Comment: @Gianlucca i finally got it to work, had to go with marchin 's idea of while loop, i did switch some stuff around because i kept messing with it and after trying it 10 times it is working

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea with `Java 8 Stream.`

```
//ofcourse you can remove numOfElement from method signature. i didnt use.
public static boolean hasDuplicate(int numOfElement, int[] numArr) {

    List<Integer> numArrList = Arrays.stream(numArr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new HashSet<Integer>(numArrList).size() != numArrList.size();
}
```